# Render time increased to 2 hours just by adding color

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, image, gpu, osx

I am learning blender through the Donut tutorial by Blender Guru on Youtube. I rendered this image and it took a few minutes.
[image]

Then in the next video where he explained materials and added colors, I tried to render again by adding the materials and suddenly it says it is gonna take 2 hours!! Here is the screenshot of the new rendering process.
[image]

I am using Macbook Air M1, Blender V3.1. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Here is the link to the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GbwNPk8yR06lqDvLCvGdv9Zpt1rsY2W8/view?usp=sharing). Also I know that M1 MacBook air comes with a 7 core GPU. But I cannot find the Cycles Render Devices under settings. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change the time limit value to e.g. 5 secs (or how long you want to wait)

[image]

Yes, this will decrease your quality. But for impatient people this settings is perfect.

Also you can try to change to GPU. Might be quicker.

Comment: Hey thanks. That worked. And about that GPU part like I said, I can't find the option to select the GPU in preferences like they show in all the tutorials.

Comment: you are welcome. please check the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using 3.1 for native metal support.  Try enabling *Experimental Feature Set* in Cycles.  I think this will let you choose your render device in preferences.

[image]